# How can I use a variable value to call a dataframe?

Tags: python, variables, pandas, dataframe

Say that I'm given a dataframe that summarizes different companies:

```
summary=pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Company Name', 'Formation Date', 'Revenue', 'Profit', 'Loss'])
```

And then say each company in that dataframe has its own corresponding dataframe, named after the company, giving a more in-depth picture of the company's history and stats.  Something like:

```
exampleco=pandas.Dataframe(columns=['Date', 'Daily Profit', 'Daily Loss', 'Daily Revenue'])
```

I have a script that processes each row of the `summary` dataframe, but I would like to grab the name from `row['Company Name']` and use it to access the company's own dataframe.

In other words I'd love it if there was something that worked like this:

```
.
.
>>> company=row['Company Name']
>>> pandas.get_dataframe_from_variable(company)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: ['Date', 'Daily Profit', 'Daily Loss', 'Daily Revenue']
Index: []

[0 rows x 2 columns]
.
.
```

Any ideas of how I might get this to work would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do these dataframes exist or you want to generate them?

Comment: @EdChum Hi Ed.  No, they exist, I just used the syntax above in an attempt to concisely get the point across; though I see it might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are asking, the problem here is that the names are stored as strings and you cannot evaluate these as dataframes I think as they are strings and not dataframes, even if you used `ast.literal_eval` you can only evaluate structures that are strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans and None. So you can either just store the dataframe in your dataframe or just construct a dict of your dataframe using the names as keys and the dataframes as values is I think the best approach

Comment: @EdChum  Thanks ed, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to contain your DataFrames and use strings as the keys.

```
companies = {'company1':pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Daily Profit', 
                                                 'Daily Loss', 'Daily Revenue']), 
             'company2':pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Daily Profit',
                                                 'Daily Loss', 'Daily Revenue'])}

company=row['Company Name'] # Get your company name as a string from your summary.
company_details = companies[company] # Returns a DataFrame.
```